# Ubuntu Sort Command, does not work with diffrent encodings

Tags: sorting, character-encoding, ubuntu-14.04, iso-8859-1

i have a document, and i want to sort it with this: 
sort -k1,1 -k2,2n -k4,4n

if the file does not contain stuff like ü,ä,ö or what ever it works. But if it does this sorting is not right.

The file is in Ascii

So before the document is sorted: its like this

übersetzt
Bethoven
bibliothek

And after sorting its:

Bethoven
übersetzt
bibliothek

So it's worng, actually the sorting command ignores the ü, and thinks bersezt is before bibliothek.

Do you know how i can deal with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to deal with special chars like ü,ö,ä.
If someone will have an similiar problem, here is how i fixed it:

```
sed -i -r -e 'y/äöüÄÖÜß/{|}¢µ¼¥/' path/to/file

LC_ALL=C sort -f path/to/file > path/to/file-sorted

sed -i -r -e 'y/{|}¢µ¼¥/äöüÄÖÜß/' path/to/file-sorted
```